# Salesforce authentication failure

Tags: api, oauth2, curl, postman

[image]

I am trying to POST to the API Endpoint https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
as shown in the screenshot

this is the first step towards authentication which is failing and giving an error of "invalid grant", "authentication failure"

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone point out my mistake

I have tried the solution in this example
[{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339872/errorinvalid-grant-error-descriptionauthentication-failure)
but it didn't work for me

Edit:
I have tried different urls ,
different grant_types
differnt username and password

I have tried test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
I have tried midwich4.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

I have tried using curl
or postman both

the result is same for all three urls
error:invalid grant -> "error_description":authentication failure

Comment: there is more than 1 post on this site with troubleshooting steps for this error. also, a screenshot with the method, url and error wont help much in this case, you will probably want to ensure your headers are properly set.

Comment: I have tried all examples. and I am still unclear on what i am doing incorrectly, everything gives invalid_grant error

Comment: as previously mentioned, you will need to share more info on what you have tried and request data for us to help.

Comment: Also, why are you using username/password? nowadays, this is not really a recommended approach.

Comment: Hi @glls , Thanks , for your response  . I am new to stackExchange , I have included some more details.

Comment: I would like to know what is the recommended approach

Comment: There are very many ways an OAuth flow can go wrong and produce the same error, which can make troubleshooting a challenge. The fact that you're trying different login URLs suggests you may not have clarity on which environment you have credentials for - `test.salesforce.com` and `login.salesforce.com` are completely separate. Additionally, it looks like you probably have not appended your security token to your password.

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&language=en_US&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: Thankyou ! it was precisely my problem , i was not appending the security token! you are a genius!

Comment: make sure you "accept the answer" if it provided useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The critical note from [OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow for Special Scenarios](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) says:

> When using the username-password flow with an API, create a field in the username and password login screen where users can enter their security token. The security token is an automatically generated key that must be added to the end of the password to log in to Salesforce from an untrusted network. **Concatenate the password and token when passing the request for authentication.**

(Emphasis mine; this turns out to be the problem here).

OAuth flows can present generic errors for a wide variety of issues, including this one; it's critical to follow the setup instructions to the letter, as well as maintaining awareness of configuration (such as IP restrictions) in the specific Salesforce environment you are using.

---

It is also important to note that the Username-Password Flow should *not* be used in production for integration activities. Use the Username-Password Flow only for, as the documentation says, special scenarios - such as one-off testing. In production, use the Web Server or JWT Flow, which avoid storing user credentials and survive a password reset.